# Use of Cauchy's intergral theorem (and consequences).

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an analytical function, with $|f(z)|\leq\displaystyle\frac{1}{1-|z|}$ for $|z|<1$. I have to prove that :

$\left|\displaystyle\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\right|\leq(n+1)\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n<(n+1)e$

The last inequality is known, but I'm having some trouble with the first one. I tried using the fact that, for $0<r<1$ we have :

$\left|\displaystyle\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}\right|\leq\frac{1}{r^n}\sup_{t\in[0,2\pi]}\{|f(re^{it})|\}$, here $=\displaystyle\frac{1}{r^n}\times\frac{1}{1-r}$

But it's not leading me anywhere, apparently. My other idea was trying to prove that :

$\displaystyle\left|1+\sum_{n\geq1}(n+1)\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^nz^n\right|\geq\frac{1}{1-|z|}\left(=\sum_{n\geq0}|z|^n\mbox{ since }|z|<1\right)$

But I keep getting stuck with the inequalities. Could anybody help me ?

Comment: Find the $r\in [0,1]$ that maximizes $(1-r)r^n.$

Comment: Can you give me a hint about how to do that ? That's what I was thinking but I don't know how to start.

Comment: Take the derivative and set it equal to $0.$

Comment: Oh, yeah right, 0 was not the only solution. Thank you, again.